# Hosting WCF service

Tags: wcf

I am following [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link to create my wcf service and hosting through window service its is working fine but when i change my namespace from "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples" to "EE.ServiceProcess.ABC" and do changes accordingly in app.config my window service dont get start properly
my
App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="EE.ServiceProcess.ABC.CalculatorService"
                   behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/EEServiceProcessABCservice/service"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/EEServiceProcessABCservice/service  -->
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="wsHttpBinding"
                      contract=" EE.ServiceProcess.ABC.ICalculator" />
            <!-- the mex endpoint is explosed at http://localhost:8000/EEServiceProcessABCservice/service/mex -->
            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
   </configuration>
```

Can any one please suggest where am i going wrong?

Comment: Your CLR Name space and Contract should match. Give the same CLR namespace in Confing file.

Comment: What is the error message? Put `try catch` block and intercept the message.

Comment: _"my window service dont get start properly"_ - please show any exceptions you get.

Comment: Have you updated this line [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]